# Error: Could not find or load main class calculator.Calculator /home/kubuntu/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.scanner

My complete code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       double n1, n2;
       String operation;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
            n1 = scan.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
            n2 = scan.nextDouble();

            Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter +,-,/: ");
            operation = op.next();

            switch (operation)  {
                case "+":
                    System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 + n2));
                    break;

                case "-":
                    System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 - n2));
                    break;

                case "/":
                    System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 / n2));
                    break;

                 case "*":
                    System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 * n2));
                    break;

                 default: 
                     System.out.println("You are finished");         
       } 
    } 
}
```

I am currently trying to create a calculator.
If anyone is ABLE to help, it would be much appreciated.
(if you could also that add simple comments that would be great too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one operator :)

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

And it works fine for me then.

Comment: When you will be able, please do so.  So that this will disappear from unresolved questions pool.

Comment: I just tried running it and this came up: Error: Could not find or load main class calculator.Calculator
/home/kubuntu/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: This is connected with your local Netbeans, try restarting it. This code works fine with me, on InteliJ. Try then cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: I just added this to the code: package calculator; and it works thanks for your help